# Are there animals that celebrate communally?

Tags: behavior, socializing

Are there any animals that are known to celebrate events? For example, we humans might celebrate a birthday or passing an important test. An event causes us to perform some sort of celebration that is motivated simply by joy and not any sort of survival instinct.

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic as it's not really about pets, but it would be on-topic on Biology.SE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, not birthdays or other human-made events but lots of social animals celebrate in groups.

One example is chimpanzees.  When one finds a cache of fruit, they shout out to their friends, who typically come and join in their celebration by shrieking. Chimps also celebrate after successfully raiding a neighboring group.

Elephants have also been known to return to the site where an in-group member has died.  Not sure if this counts as a celebration, but it's a communal recognition of an event.